# Host A in VLAN is not responding to ping from host B, but host A can ping host B

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, vlan, opnsense

Overview: I have a issue where one host A in VLAN is not responding to ping from host B, but host A can ping host B .

A= Windows and B=Linux, VLAN=10.
A IP address = 192.168.10.100,
B IP address = 192.168.10.102.

On both hosts, the other hosts MAC address are visible using `arp -a`.

Environment:  VLAN ID=10 on Port 3(Machine A) and Port 5(Machine B) on TP link Switch.

Firewall rules are created on OPNSense and DHCP enabled in VLAN 10 Profile.

Problem 1: A can ping B, but B can not can ping A. Could you please guide me here?

Problem 2: For VLAN=10 Interface in OPNsense Firewall Rule I have set PASS for all IPv4 and IPV6 from source = <VLAN_Interface_Name>_net to destination = all. I have cloned the existing Rules for LAN and change the interfaces accordingly to <VLAN_Interface_Name>,  but I don't know why I am not able to access Internet from the host connected to that VLAN.

I am a pretty new to networking, I would appreciate if one can guide me here and recommend some material which help me with understanding how to design rules in OPNsense firewall and what's the purpose of Tagged and Untagged ports in switches for VLAN configuration.

Comment: Assuming that the Windows Firewall is on in Machine_A, make sure that the **File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)** inbound rule is enabled for the correct firewall/network profile.

Comment: Pretty typical issue usually caused by the *stateful firewall* operating on machine A. This is not quite about networking but about system administration on the machine A.